# How to access FTP server in android

Tags: android, ftp

I am working on a project where I need to access FTP server using its domain, username and password. I want to save data and retrieve data from there.

Please suggest any solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Look for commons net apache library - http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/. It provides a tools for work with FTP.

Code example for download video file.

```
    FileOutputStream videoOut;
    File targetFile = new File("path");

    FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
    try {
        ftpClient.connect("your.ftp.address", 21);
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        ftpClient.login("login", "password");

        ftpClient.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);// Used for video
        targetFile.createNewFile();
        videoOut = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);
        boolean result=ftpClient.retrieveFile("/" + "filename-to-download", videoOut);

        ftpClient.disconnect();
        videoOut.close();    

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I don't work with file upload but I think there are a lot of examples in web.

Answer (score 0):

To `Upload file`, I used this code in one project. I got code from this link : [FTPS](https://github.com/Abhan/FTPS)

Also, this guys is using it in secured way.

I hope this can help you out.